# Perforce recommended Baseline

Tags: perforce, clearcase

I am migrating from Clearcase to Perforce.

Clearcase has a concept of "Recommended Baseline".  Is there a similar concept in Perforce?

Also I think that the recommended baseline in clearcase is just a "Floating label".  Is that correct?  If so is there a floating label concept in Perforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [recommended baseline](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21226431) isn't a floating label.
It designated a label (or baseline, which won't float) used to rebase the child stream with said baseline.
You can change the recommended baseline (without triggering any rebase), but that doesn't make it "floating".

As such, it is a marker to reference to baseline which could be used to initialize or update any sub-stream.

The [Perforce directory Standard](http://www.perforce.com/sites/default/files/pds_template.zip) (zip file with a ppt in it) is there to establish "Common elements conveyed by directory structure (non-streams) or stream model".

You find the idea of "sharable quality" labels which can then be used to initialize another stream (here "Patch").
But I didn't found any specific p4 operation which would mark  that label as the one to use by default, like "recommended baseline" in ClearCase does.

[image: P4 stream example]

(This is an example of a lifecycle phase from the PDS document, one process amongst many)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's exactly equivalent, but Perforce promotes a mainline branching model for each product or component.  In normal cases the recommended baseline would simply be the latest on the main branch.  Work isn't promoted to main until it reaches a point of useful stability, while release branches isolate legacy bug fixes and customizations.

This blog post is a good starting point:

http://www.perforce.com/blog/100607/perforce-directory-standard-pds

The author is very helpful and used to be a ClearCase administrator, so you can leave some comments for him.